# Plastic Pots OR Ceramic pots, which is better in terms of plant health?

Tags: indoors, containers, pots

Are their any advantage of having plastic pots over ceramic pots except below points:

```
1. Lower cost.
2. Fungus will not grow on Plastic
3. un-breakable, good life.
```

all of above point are not considering plant health and its growth, So I am asking which of the two is in **favor of plant health** and why?

Comment: I believe the advantages are for the people, not the plants. In addition to cost and breakability, consider also the weight - a large ceramic pot is heavy

Comment: Yes, agreed. Earlier I was thinking plastic container are not good for plants.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've only asked about ceramic versus plastic pots from the plant point of view, so that's what I'll answer. If the ceramic pot is glazed, then the water retention will be about the same as a plastic pot, but because the material might be thick walled, they may be slightly more insulating against heat and cold than plastic, but the difference will be negligible. In truth, it doesn't really matter to the plant - what matters is that it has sufficient room for its roots, that the roots don't freeze in winter nor bake in summer (as in metal pots), and that the pot has good drainage and is watered as and when necessary.

Comment: does it means that material of container doesn't matter much except metal as it doesn't shield the plant from heat and cold.

Comment: That's right - what is more important is the right size for the right plant, and potting on when necessary. Wood is another option - rots over time, but much more insulating for plant roots.